# Swift 3 Game Music Play

Tags: ios, audio, swift3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a single view application with a few view each having their own view controller class. I also have a game game and a game view controller, I was wondering how I could play a game music starting from the start screen view controller and have it continue to play through out all of my views and game scene? So that way I don't have to say play when x-screen is loaded so it doesn't restart every time the player changes views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play the music form your `AppDelegate`.  Put this code in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundName", withExtension: "mp3")!
var player: AVAudioPlayer!

do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    guard let player = player else { return }

    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This will play the music as soon as your app is launched and continue until told to stop or the app closes.

Comment: did you mean? @TheValyreanGroup

Comment: @shane  What do you mean?

Comment: did you mean put this

Comment: func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundName", withExtension: "mp3")!
        var player: AVAudioPlayer!
        
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

Comment: there is no didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() @TheValyreanGroup

Comment: Yes, sorry.  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was Swift 2.  I've updated.